# Computing length of a closed path given a spatial metric

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, geometry

I'm trying to self-study the "cosmology" chapter in Gravitation and Spacetime
By Hans C. Ohanian and Remo Ruffini, and I'm stuck on the wording in problem 9.6:

The spatial line element for a homogeneous and isotropic 3-space with positive curvature is
$$ds^2 = R^2\left[\frac{dr^2}{1-r^2/a^2}+r^2(d\theta^2+\sin^2\theta d\phi^2) \right].$$

(a) What is the measured length of a path that starts at one point and proceeds once around the entire universe, on the straightest possible line?

(b) Consider a circle $r=b$ around the origin. What is the surface area of this circle? Show that for $r \to 0$ that your answer has the expected form.

(c) What is the maximum surface area that any circle in this universe can have?

I don't really understand how to approach (a) and (b), what is meant by "the straighest possible line"? Which value of $r$ do I pick to start the path for problem (a)? Also, in part (b), how does one find a surface area given the line element?

The chapter in this book is not entirely clear. Any help is appreaciated!

Comment: “Straightest possible line” means “geodesic”. Have you learned about geodesics?

Comment: @G.Smith Yes, but I'm not sure how to compute the length of a geodesic from a point to the same point..

Comment: @G.Smith Since the geodesics for this metric are when $d\theta = d\phi = 0$, how would I compute the geodesic length for a closed path?

Answer (score 0):

Since you know your space is homogeneous and isotropic, you may think
of the simplest possible geodesic: the one starting at $r=0$ and going
on with $\theta$ and $\phi$ constant.

I don't remember how those authors approach the matter, so I'll suggest
a way of my own, i.e. changing coordinate $r$ to $u$ such that
$r=a\,\sin u$. Can you see which value of $u$ brings you again to the
starting point $r=0\,$?